# calling a javascript function with multiple closures

Tags: javascript, function, closures

```
    function sum(a) {
        var sum = a
        function f(b) {
            sum += b
            return f
        }

        f.toString = function () { return sum }
        return f
    }
    var a = sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
```

Can someone explain to me how does this code works? I really don't get how to call function with multiple closures in such a way.
And why when i print a in the browsers console the result is "function 15" and not just 15

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: There is only one closure here.

Comment: (0)- 1 closure (1)-2nd closure etc..?

Comment: No; those all return the same function (`return f`)

Answer (score 2):

> And why when i print a in the browsers console the result is "function 15" and not just 15

To get final result you should call `toString` function. This closure holds the sum until you call `toString` function.

```js
function sum(a) {
    var sum = a

    function f(b) {
        sum += b
        return f
    }

    f.toString = function() {
        return sum;
    }
    return f
}

var a = sum(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);

document.write(a.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum(0)` returns a function `f` that closes over the local variable `sum` (the only closure in that code). Because it returns a function it means you can call that function which also accepts an argument and returns itself which is how you can keep chaining like that.

```
sum(0) // `sum` is 0, returns f (a function)
sum(0)(1) // returns f which adds 1 to `sum` and returns f again
// and again etc
```

Another way of thinking about it:

```
var fn0 = sum(0) // `sum` is 0, returns f (a function)
var fn1 = fn0(1) // returns f which adds 1 to `sum` and returns f again
var fn2 = fn1(2) // ...
```